# how to get last value of a column, based on two categories in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that contains columns called date, shift, value, price and distance.I want to extract last value for each date and shift from the "value" column. For example for each day, there are two rows one contains datetime,shift(day or night) and last datapoints from value for each shift.

This is the sample of my data frame:

[image]

Expected Outcome:

[image]

This is what I got: But here I cant include price and distance column for selected row

```
df['day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df.groupby(['day','shift'])['value'].agg(list).apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is loaded into a Pandas DataFrame, you can simply group by those two fields and use the [last() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) as such:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').date())
df.groupby(['date', 'shift']).last()
```

Edit: This results in the following output:

[image]

I also added two lines of code to show how I converted datetime strings to dates for completeness purposes.

Comment: no, I want to extract the last value for each date and shift from the "value" column.Kindly check the expected  Outcome.

Comment: @kevin this is exactly what my answer does. I have loaded your sample data in a dataframe, executed the code as per my answer and resulted with your expected output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that's what I was looking for